# MySQL Query to select multiple entries based selection of dropdownlist entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am having a logic issue with a MySQL Query and hoping for some advice on what type of refinement to use.

for the purposes of explaining the problem imagine you have 3 dropdown lists called ListA, ListB and ListC. ListA has a population of Cat1, Cat2, Cat3, ListB, Cat4, Cat5,...and so on.

So there are 9 categories in total spread across 3 lists. These lists are generated by scanning a database for distinct entries and then populating the list so the search refinement will automatically grow as new entries and categories are created.

My issue is the selection query for multiple categories as I want the user to be able to choose how refined a search they run. So using ListA will give a little refinement, ListA and ListB will refine more and so on, like most search engines. But my query requires a 100% data entry to select as if nothing is entered it will look for an empty space which will never occur and thus gives back nothing.

All the variables are sent by post and stored as variables in the processing page by collecting them and then assigning them to variables using if statements for detecting values, at first I thought I could fill the entry with an arbitrary value if it was empty, but I cant find one that will always be true, I looked at BOOLEAN but couldnt make it work either.

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM classifieds WHERE listA = "'.listA.'" AND listB = "'.listB.'" AND listC = "'.listC.'"
```

The query needs to be AND logic so it looks for entries filling all requirements, but if for example ListB was not populated as the user was not bothered by that field (say it was price and the user is not concerned with that), how can I have it ignore that section or have it not be picky.

Is there a universal query for a where clause that I can use to select it even if its blank?

I'm sure there will be some duplicate on here but I am not sure what it will be called as everythign I have seen so far is totally different. I know I can do it with prepared queries but I would need to set up a logic array for every combination of active boxes and while that's fine for 2-3, I have 10+ of these selectors and that's too much for a selection.

Can anyone help me out as to what direction to look into to accomplish this task? it seems ridiculously simple but a pain to make work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write query on condition based. For and example,

Following code will give you to access only the variables which USER Selected and your query runs on base of users serach criteria.

```
    $whereArr = array();
    if(isset($_REQUEST['listA'])) {
        $whereArr[] = " listA = '" . $_REQUEST['listA'] . "'";
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['listB'])) {
        $whereArr[] = " listB = '" . $_REQUEST['listB'] . "'";
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['listC'])) {
        $whereArr[] = " listC = '" . $_REQUEST['listC'] . "'";
    }

    $where_Clause = " ";
    if(count($whereArr) > 0) {
        $where_Clause = " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $whereArr);
    }


    $query = "SELECT * FROM classifieds " . $where_Clause;
```

Answer (score 1):

would this help?

```
where ("'.listA.'" = '' or listA = "'.listA.'")
  and ("'.listB.'" = '' or listB = "'.listB.'")
  and ("'.listC.'" = '' or listC = "'.listC.'")
```

Answer (score 0):

take a variable that describe your filters as:

```
string filters = "where ";
```

suppose you are having 10 filters namely A,B,C..... keep them in array
while traversing through the array, check which one of them is selected and add it to the filter variable as:

```
filter+="listA='sometext'";// here filter A was selected
```

similarly you can add other filters.

```
filter+="and listB='sometext'";// here filter B was selected after A ,while traversing through the loop;
```

Make out some tweak to add 'and' after second filter onwards

the filter string would now read as

```
filter = "select * from table where listA='sometext' and listB='sometext'";
```

and then use the variable filter in query string as:

```
query="select * from table "+filter;
```

(take care of required whitespaces in between)

Hope this helps

Comment: Ive set this up but if nothing is selected, i.e. the user wants to see everything, it still places a WHERE after the table name by default. Is there any way to avoid this using a multi conditional if statement to detect anything?? P.S. any idea what was wrong with my question to get downvoted, I tried to make it as clear as possible yet it got a -1 straight off and now the forum is warning me about asking useless questions, the comment on the top of it is something about ODBC drives that makes no sense at all .

Comment: To get rid of extraneous 'where' in case of no filters selected you can initially define filter variable as  String filter = "";             then set boolean flag as false and set it true as soon as you encounter any pf filter to get utilized. And at the end if flag is true then prefix your filter as filter = "where " + filter;